Fetch API Returns null After Closing and Reopening a Tab in Playwright E2E Test
I'm currently writing an E2E test using Playwright to simulate resuming a quiz session after closing and reopening a browser tab. The issue I'm encountering is that after reopening the tab, the fetch request to retrieve data from the API returns null, even though the localStorage data persists correctly.
this is my full code: https://gist.github.com/zpenct/2ef66b86e9eba62aced034991b2313c3
Here's ful scenario:

I start the test by clearing and setting some initial values in localStorage, which includes the user's session data (e.g., the current question number).

The test proceeds to answer a couple of questions, then the browser tab is closed.

When the tab is reopened, I expect the app to fetch the entire set of questions from the API and resume the quiz at the specific question saved in localStorage
Important Detail:

In localStorage, I'm only saving the current question number (e.g., question 3).

Upon reopening the tab, the fetch call should retrieve the entire list of questions from the API, and the application should display the question corresponding to the saved question number (e.g., questions[3]).

However, while the localStorage values like the current question number remain intact, the fetch call to retrieve the list of questions returns null, causing the app to not properly resume the quiz.


import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test.describe('Quiz Application - Resume Session', () => {
  const user = { username: 'Heoo' };

  test('should resume quiz session after closing and reopening the page', async ({ browser }) => {
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    let page = await context.newPage();

    // Step 1: Navigate to the application and set up initial state
    await page.goto('http://localhost:5173');
    await page.evaluate(() => localStorage.clear());
    await page.evaluate((user) => localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user)), user);
    await page.reload();

    // Step 2: Ensure the quiz page is open
    const questionSection = page.locator('[data-testid="question-section"]');
    await expect(questionSection).toBeVisible();

    // Step 3: Answer first two questions
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      const optionFalse = page.locator('[data-testid="option-false"]');
      await optionFalse.click();
      await page.waitForTimeout(500); // Add a small delay to ensure state updates
    }

    // Step 4: Verify we're on the third question
    const currentQuestionBefore = page.locator('[data-testid="current-question"]');
    await expect(currentQuestionBefore).toHaveText('3/5');

    // Step 5: Simulate closing the page
    await page.close();

    // Step 6: Open a new page in the same context
    page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://localhost:5173');
    await page.waitForTimeout(4000);

    const cq = await page.evaluate(() => localStorage.getItem("currentQuestion"));
    const exp = await page.evaluate(() => localStorage.getItem("expirationTime"));

    console.log({cq,exp})

    // Add a delay to ensure the page has time to load and process localStorage
    await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

    // Step 7: Ensure the quiz page is open after reopening
    await expect(page.locator('[data-testid="question-section"]')).toBeVisible();

    // Step 8: Check if the quiz resumed at the correct question
    const currentQuestionAfter = page.locator('[data-testid="current-question"]');
    await expect(currentQuestionAfter).toHaveText('3/5');

    // Step 9: Ensure the quiz is not finished
    const latestResult = page.locator('[data-testid="latest-result"]');
    await expect(latestResult).not.toBeVisible();

    // Step 10: Try answering another question to ensure the quiz is still functional
    const optionTrue = page.locator('[data-testid="option-true"]');
    await optionTrue.click();
    await page.waitForTimeout(500);

    // Verify we've moved to the next question
    await expect(currentQuestionAfter).toHaveText('4/5');

    await context.close();
  });
});





Problem:

The issue occurs when reopening the tab; while the localStorage still contains the correct currentQuestion value (e.g., 3), the fetch API request to retrieve the full set of questions returns null, leading to an incorrect state where the quiz cannot resume correctly.

My questions:

Why is the fetch API returning null after reopening the tab even though the localStorage contains the correct data?

Could this issue be related to how the API is being fetched after reopening the tab? Or is there something specific in Playwright's handling of browser contexts I should be aware of?

How can I ensure that the fetch call correctly retrieves the full set of questions and the application resumes at the correct question?


Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Can you share the application under test? It's hard to see any problems just eyeballing the test in isolation, as the existing answer attempt indicates. To really diagnose it, the page should be provided (minimally, preferably). Timeouts are flakey and shouldn't be used, by the way--use a real predicate like a locator click() or waitFor(), wait for network state, response or waitForFunction.

The issue you've described sounds like a defect with the API, if all of the assumptions you outlined are correct. From a syntax perspective, your test is written correctly.
Does the API respond with a 200 and a null body, or a different response code?
Are you sure the endpoint that establishes state for your application is the one that is returning null? Providing more context about the implementation of the system under test may point to the issue more clearly.
Have you asked the developers of the application you're testing what the expected behavior is on a session resume? As this is an end-to-end test, it should normally be sufficient to "do what a user would do" and wait the allowed amount of delay for the system to pass assertions without interrogating the implementation (local storage, API payloads, etc). As recommended by Playwright's docs: test user-visible behavior
